# Detect new visual selection with vimscript

Tags: vimscript, autocmd, visual-mode

I asked a [related but different question
here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/36692/31858).

I'm writing the
[vim-visual-history](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/vim-visual-history)
plugin that keeps a traversable history of previous visual selections. To
detect the selections, I'm using:

```
autocmd CursorMoved * call <SID>update_visual_mark_list()
```

then I check if the cursor was moved in visual mode, and if so I record it in
the history:

```
function! s:update_visual_mark_list()
    let mode = mode()
    if mode ==# 'v' || mode ==# 'V' || mode ==# "\<C-V>"

        " enter the current selection into history

    endif
endfunction
```

The problem with this approach is that it's possible to visually select some
text without moving the cursor, e.g. a single press of `V` will select the
current line, but this isn't picked up by my method. You can see in this demo
that I have to do `Vl` instead of just `V` to get the lines picked up:

[image]

Is there a way to detect when visual mode is entered, even if the cursor didn't
move? There doesn't seem to be an `autocmd` to do it (something analogous
`InsertEnter` would have been ideal or if there existed a `NormalLeave`). I
know about `visualmode()`, but I don't see a way to use it to fix this issue.

Comment: By that same question of yours I already mentioned `:h ModeChanged` event. I don't see why you need `CursorMoved` at all. Just catch "Visual-to-Normal" transition and store the values of marks once. What really bothers me is how "lengthy" history can be of such importance? I mean, these are just line/col numbers. They may become invalid after almost any editing operation. Why does a user need them, except the last known selection that is already saved by Vim?

Comment: @Matt ah I missed the ModeChanged line in your previous answer (there I was too focused on why I was missing some visual modes). And I hadn't thought about the fact that the line/col numbers would likely be invalidated after edits.. Originally I was focused on solving a slightly different problem - that of reversing the last visual selection when doing a series of `a}` in visual mode. I will add a mechanism to reset/remove old history when edits to the text occur. Thanks for pointing this out!